# Short story about a teenager that uses his allowance to replace his body parts with bionic parts

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm looking for a sci fi short story about a teenager that uses his allowance to replace his body parts with bionic parts. It's an older story probably from before 1970. His parents are upset that he is "rebelling" and replacing himself bit by bit with bionic parts. I'm remembering this story being called "Friday… something."

Comment: According to ISFDB (www.isfdb.org), there aren't very many short stories with titles including the word "Friday" and a publication date before 1975. You could try their advanced search and see if anything looks familiar.

Comment: Sounds like a story I read in Analog. The teen is just about to get his eyes replaced with implants that make life seem better and his father stages an intervention.